# "Access violation reading location" error in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, for-loop

I need to write a program which contains an array with an alphabet (tab1), an array with pointers (tab2) and an array that stores a word given by the user (tab2). So far it looks like this:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    #define W 5
    #define K 5
    #define D 24

    int main(){
        char tab1[W][K] = {
            'a', 'f', 'k', 'p', 'w',
            'b', 'g', 'l', 'r', 'x',
            'c', 'h', 'm', 's', 'y',
            'd', 'i', 'n', 't', 'z',
            'e', 'j', 'o', 'u' };
        char *tab2[D] = { NULL };

        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
            for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++){
                printf("%c ", tab1[k][l]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        char tab3[D+1];
        printf("\nGimme some word.\n");
        fgets(tab3, 24, stdin);

    }
```

Now, I have to go through a given word, check where (in tab1) are the letters used in it and put pointers to them in tab3. Then using those pointers I'm supposed to take the data from tab1 and print the word.

```
int a = strlen(tab3);
        for (int m = 0; m < a; m++){
            for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++){
                for (int o = 0; o < 5; o++){
                    if (tab3[m] == tab1[n][o]){
                        tab2[m] = &tab1[n][o];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int p = 0; p < (a + 1); p++){
            printf("%c", *tab2[p]);
        }
```

It does compile, but when I run it, it goes to the point where I'm giving the asked word and press enter it stops and gives this error: 
Unhandled exception at 0x00CD409D in ConsoleApplication17.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

I can't tell where I'm making a mistake and I'm getting crazy, please, can somebody help me?

Comment: what's the input/expected output and what is your current problem? have you tried debugging/printing?

Comment: We are not a debugging service. Use your debugger and provide a **specific** problem. Read [ask].

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre input is a single word a user is giving at the end of first part of the code and expected output is: first an array with alphabet (which works), a command for a user to give a word and then, the program is supposed to print this word using pointers from tab3.

Comment: @Olaf program goes on, sometimes even prints out what I want and then it stops and says "Unhandled exception at 0x00CD409D in ConsoleApplication17.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

Comment: `char tab1[W][K] = {
            'a', 'f', 'k', 'p', 'w',` that sounds _wrong_. It's a 2D array intialized as a 1D array.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre how is it initialized as a 1D array? That's how I've been thought to fill it and also checked it online and it doesn't seem to be a problem. It also prints out well using for - loop.
**Edit:** I fixed it and put each verse in {}, but the error and everything is the same

Comment: Did you use your debugger? If so, where does the crash occur?

Comment: You have a null pointer problem somewhere.

Comment: Do you really have code outside of `main`?

Comment: That's not debugging, that's exatly asking us to debug your code. Again: Use the debugger! If you don't know what that is: there are search engines on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Access violation reading location 0x00000000" means your program is trying to read memory at location 0x0, which will result in exceptions. One of the elements of array tab2 is having value zero, when you are trying to de-reference it.
The correct way to solve this problem is to check your algorithm and make sure that this scenario can not happen (You are dereferencing pointer variables that were not set properly).
A safe way to handle these situations is to do a null check before dereferencing a pointer.
In your case, (for readability)

```
if(tab2[p] != NULL)
{
    printf("%c", *tab2[p]);
}
else
{
    printf("This pointer is not yet initialized!");
}
```

Please note that this will not catch other invalid addresses that the pointer might hold. In your case, it will work since you initialize all pointers in tab2 to NULL.
Also note that safety mechanisms are NO SUBSTITUTE for solid Algorithms.